# Pull unique values from mysql table and order by number of occurrences

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a little trouble with this, I found how to get unique values from multiple columns, and I know how to sort normally, but I can't seem to mix the two

The original sql statement is here:

```
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT UserID, UserIP FROM Visits WHERE PageID='".$_GET['p']."'";
```

It only gets the first instance of where both values are unique, so doing the 'mysql_numrows' thing doesn't work.

This is from within the fetch array loop, it can count the occurrences fine, but at that point it's a bit too late to sort

```
$sql5="SELECT Date, VisitID FROM Visits WHERE PageID='".$_GET['p']."' AND UserID='".$userid."' AND UserIP='".$userip."' ORDER BY Date";
$result5 = mysql_query($sql5);
$num5 = mysql_numrows($result5);
```

Basically, it should get unique values based on both columns, count how many times the appear, sort by count, then potentially also sort by the highest matching date if possible

Any suggestions would be great, cheers :)

Also it's just for a personal site, I'm not actually doing anything with the info, just trying to learn some more php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `GROUP BY`, like this:

```
SELECT UserID, UserIP FROM Visits 
WHERE PageID = ###
GROUP BY UserID, UserIP
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, max(`Date`) DESC
```

Comment: Ahh thanks a lot, seems to work really well. One question though, there's another column called 'date', I slightly modified your code to include this, and added it to the end to say 'ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, Date DESC'. It doesn't do anything though, which I'm guessing is because of the count(*) part, how exactly would I get it working?

Comment: @Peter you cannot simple use one column value if you are using `GROUP BY`. You'll have to use a grouping function like `MAX`. Please see my updated answer above.

Comment: Ah yeah that makes sense, never done anything like that before but at least I know now, cheers for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Please change your query like

```
$sql = "SELECT UserID, UserIP FROM Visits 
WHERE PageID = '".$_GET['p']."'
GROUP BY UserID, UserIP
ORDER BY COUNT(UserID) DESC";
```

let me know if helpful to you.

Thanks

Comment: Hey thanks, it does work fine, although I can't seem to sort the results by date too (so any with the same count get ordered by the date value), simply adjusting the select part and adding ', Date DESC' onto the end doesn't work, would you happen to know how to do this? cheers :)

Comment: Can you please paste query here so, i check what exactly looking and do you want Date DESC ?